# VS2013: Can't add reference to a project in the same solution

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to do a basic operation, which is just adding reference to a project that's in the same solution. I'm getting the following error:

`This operation could not be completed. No such interface supported.`.

And that's all. No more info. Any idea where to start? I'm using **visual studio 2013**.

Now I'm getting a new type of error: `Package "ReferencePackageManager" failed to load.`

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try running your visual studio with "devenv.exe /log" and check in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE" for more details.

Comment: @blacai: What am I supposed to look for in that folder? I'm looking at that folder right now.

Comment: There should be a File activity log with more details inside

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

1. Launch Developer Command Prompt for VS 2013
2. Navigate to Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies directory
3. Run gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll
   (this link shows where gacutil is: https://blogs.iis.net/davcox/where-is-gacutil-exe)

**You should now see:**

Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache

Restart Visual Studio and hopefully all will be well and you can add references.

---

*Developer Command Prompt must start in **Common7** directory, if not you must navigate to it before step 2.*

*if you can't find Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.**11.0**.dll with **11.0** version, try another high version*

---

**To launch Developer Command Prompt for VS 2013, do:**

**In Windows 10**

1. Open the Start menu, by pressing the Windows logo key Windows logo
   on your keyboard for example.
2. On the Start menu, enter dev. This will bring a list of installed
   apps that match your search pattern. If you're looking for a
   different command prompt, try entering a different search term such
   as prompt.
3. Choose the Developer Command Prompt (or the command prompt you want
   to use).

**In Windows 8.1**

1. Go to the Start screen, by pressing the Windows logo key Windows
   logo on your keyboard for example.
2. On the Start screen, press CTRL + TAB to open the Apps list and then
   enter V. This will bring a list that includes all installed Visual
   Studio command prompts.
3. Choose the Developer Command Prompt (or the command prompt you want
   to use).

**In Windows 8**

1. Go to the Start screen, by pressing the Windows logo key Windows
   logo on your keyboard for example.
2. On the Start screen, press the Windows logo key Windows logo + Z.
   Choose the Apps view icon at the bottom of the screen and then enter
   V. This will bring a list that includes all installed Visual Studio
   command prompts.
3. Choose the Developer Command Prompt (or the command prompt you want
   to use).

**In Windows 7**

1. Choose Start, expand All Programs, and then expand Microsoft Visual
   Studio.
2. Depending on the version of Visual Studio you have installed, choose
   Visual Studio Tools, Visual Studio Command Prompt, or the command
   prompt you want to use.

This steps worked for me.
see more at:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/4eea5785-0a83-4389-89e3-209a5a4432c0/referencemanagerpackage-fails-to-install-vs-2017-community-edition?forum=vssetup

Comment: If you not find gacutil.exe try this link: https://blogs.iis.net/davcox/where-is-gacutil-exe